# Can I have multiple wifi networks on a single MacBook Pro? [[GoPro]]

Tags: wifi

I'm looking to connect three GoPro cameras at the same time. Each GoPro needs its own network, and my computer needs to access all of them at the same time. Also, my computer needs a fourth wireless network of its own for accessing and uploading images to the internet.

Can I do this? Is it possible to have multiple connections going on at once? Is there a USB wireless adapter I could buy that would accept multiple wifi cards?

EDIT: I need to access both GoPros at the same time. If I have gopro1 and gopro2, each with their own wifi configuration, I can only access one network at a time via my computer's dropdown wifi menu. Is there any way to connect to multiple GoPro networks at the same time? I need my computer to have it's own network so I can pull photos from each GoPro simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those cameras work like the ones I've used, all you do is connect your computer and the cameras to the same Wi-Fi router, and you'll be able to do everything normally, on one network. You should never have to create multiple physical networks like that unless you're setting up a corporate network, with multiple access points.

Comment: I have gopro1, and gopro2, each with their own networks. I can connect to one of them at a time through my computer's wireless dropdown menu. I can select either gopro1 or gopro2, but i can't be connected to both at the same time. I'm looking for a way to do this.

Comment: There is no way to create multiple networks like what you're trying to do. You have to get the cameras themselves to connect to your Wi-Fi network, so that your computer can access them on the same network. Consult your camera's documentation for assistance. I have set up these cameras before, and you do have to go into your camera's setup page and direct them to connect to your network. Multiple networks isn't actually a thing for home users normally, since it's almost never needed.

Comment: so you're suggesting that if I have a network at my office called "officewifi" I need to set up the GoPros so that their networks are configured to "officewifi" instead of having their own networks?

Comment: They all have to connect to the same router. That's the basis of a modern network: Multiple devices connected to one central device, which manages access between them. Presumably you have a Wi-Fi router, possibly from Netgear, Cisco, etc. You have to tell them all to connect to your Wi-Fi router, and you will be able to access them from your computer, provided your computer is also connected to the same router.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could setup a GoPro to connect to an existing network. I thought it had to be configured with its own wireless network. To clarify my question from before -- I can configure all my GoPros to point to "officewifi" and then I'll be able to use a router?

Comment: Yep. You will need to consult the documentation to get the specifics of how to access that configuration page, however.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere that it's possible to do this. I checked the manual that's available online and have checked in with GoPro customer support. There does not seem to be any information on this, so are you able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please let me know if you can respond. Otherwise, it's misleading to suggest a solution without a way to support it.